# RecyclerView with multiple view types and data source

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am working with a recyclerView and i succeeded in inflating two views but each view content comes from different json data types. i tried passing the two datatypes in the adapter but they are not properly binded

- source code

  public class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
  {

  ```
  private Article[] mValues;
  private List<YouTubeItem> mValues2;

  Context context;

  public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Article[] items, List<YouTubeItem> item )
  {
      this.context = context;
      mValues = items;
      mValues2 = item;
  }

  public override int ItemCount
  {

      get
      {
         return mValues.Count() + mValues2.Count();
      }
  }

  public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
  {
      if (holder is SimpleViewHolder)
      try
      {
          Article item = mValues[position];
          var simpleHolder = holder as SimpleViewHolder;

          simpleHolder.mTxtView.Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.Title).ToString();
          simpleHolder.mTxtView2.Text = item.Description;


          using (var imageView = simpleHolder.mImageView)
          {
              string url = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.UrlToImage).ToString();

              //Download and display image
              UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imageView,
                  url, Resource.Drawable.cheese_1
                  );



          }
          //    simpleHolder.mprogressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          //Toast.MakeText(this.context, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
      }
      else
      {
          try
          {
              YouTubeItem item = mValues2[position];
              var simpleHolder = holder as SimpleViewHolder2;

              simpleHolder.mTxtView.Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.Title).ToString();
              // simpleHolder.mTxtView2.Text = item.DescriptionShort;


              using (var imageView = simpleHolder.mImageView)
              {
                  string url = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.MaxResThumbnailUrl).ToString();

                  //Download and display image
                  UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imageView,
                      url, Resource.Drawable.cheese_1
                      );



              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              //Toast.MakeText(this.context, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
          }

      }
  }

  public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
  {
      if ((position % 2) == 0)
      {
          //Even number
          return Resource.Layout.List_Item;
      }

      else
      {
          //Odd number
          return Resource.Layout.VideoList;
      }
  }



  public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
  {
      if (viewType == Resource.Layout.List_Item)
      {
          View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_Item, parent, false);
          view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);


          SimpleViewHolder holder = new SimpleViewHolder(view);
          // holder.mprogressbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
          // holder.mprogressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


          //Showing loading progressbar

          return holder;
      }
      else
      {
          View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.VideoList, parent, false);
          view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
          SimpleViewHolder2 holder = new SimpleViewHolder2(view);

          return holder;
      }

  }
  ```

  }

  public class SimpleViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {
      public string mBoundString;
      public readonly View mView;
      public readonly ImageView mImageView;
      public readonly TextView mTxtView;
      public readonly TextView mTxtView2;
      //   public ProgressBar mprogressbar;

  ```
  public SimpleViewHolder(View view) : base(view)
  {
      mView = view;
      mImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.avatar);
      mTxtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1);
      mTxtView2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2);
      //   mprogressbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);


  }




  public override string ToString()
  {
      return base.ToString() + " '" + mTxtView.Text;

  }
  ```

  }
  public class SimpleViewHolder2 : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {
      public string mBoundString;
      public readonly View mView;
      public readonly ImageView mImageView;
      public readonly TextView mTxtView;
      public readonly TextView mTxtView2;

  ```
  public SimpleViewHolder2(View view) : base(view)
  {
      mView = view;
      mImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.videoavatar);
      mTxtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.videoText1);
      //   mprogressbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);


  }
  ```

Comment: You will have to merge your two lists into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should merge data to one data source only. You can try this way:

1. Create data source class

   ```
   public class Data {
      int type; // 1 is article and 2 is youtubeitem
      public Article article;
      public YouTubeItem youTubeItem;
   }
   ```
2. Now merge two data source to only one

   ```
   public List<Data> merge(Articel[] articles, List<YouTubeItem> items) {
       List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Article article : articles) {
          Data data = new Data();
          data.article = article;
          data.youTubeItem = null;
          data.type = 1;
          datas.add(data);
       }

       for(YouTubeItem item : items) {
          Data data = new Data();
          data.article = null;
          data.youTubeItem = item;
          data.type = 2;
          datas.add(data);
       }

      return datas;
   }
   ```
3. Change constructor of adapter

   ```
   private List<Data> datas;

   public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Data> datas )
   {
     this.datas = datas;
   }
   ```
4. Change get Item count

   ```
   public override int ItemCount
   {

       get
       {
           return datas.Count();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Change getViewType

   ```
   public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
   {
      if (datas.get(position).type == 1)
      {
           return Resource.Layout.List_Item;
      }

      else
      {
          return Resource.Layout.VideoList;
      }
   }
   ```

**EDITED**: For merge random method

```
 public List<Data> mergeRandom(Articel[] articles, List<YouTubeItem> items) {
     List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();

     List<Integer> random = new ArrayList<>();
     int maxLength = articles.length + items.size(); 
     for(int i = 0; i< maxLength; i++) { 
        random.add(i);
     }

     while (random.size() > 0) {
        // get random item
        int index = new Random().nextInt(random.size());
        int position = random.get(index);

        if(position <= article.length - 1) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.article = articles[position];
            data.youTubeItem = null;
            data.type = 1;
            datas.add(data);
        } else {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.article = null;
            data.youTubeItem = items.get(position - article.length);
            data.type = 2;
            datas.add(data);
        }

        random.remove(index);
    }

    return datas;
 }
```

For merge odd&even method

```
List<Data> mergeOddEven(Articel[] articles, List<YouTubeItem> items) {
    List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    int articleIndex = 0;
    int youtubeIndex = 0;
    int length = articles.length + items.size();

    for(int i = 0; i< length; i++) {
        if(articleIndex >= articles.length || youtubeIndex >= items.size()) {
            if(articleIndex < articles.length) {
                for(int j = articleIndex; j < articles.length ; j++) {
                   Data data = new Data();
                   data.article = articles[j];
                   data.youTubeItem = null;
                   data.type = 1;
                   datas.add(data);

                }
            } else {
                for(int j = youtubeIndex; j < items.size() ; j++) {
                   Data data = new Data();
                   data.article = null;
                   data.youTubeItem = items.get(j);
                   data.type = 2;
                   datas.add(data);

                }
            }

            break;
        }


        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.article = articles[articleIndex];
            data.youTubeItem = null;
            data.type = 1;
            datas.add(data);

            articleIndex++;
        } else {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.article = null;
            data.youTubeItem = tems.get(youtubeIndex);
            data.type = 2;
            datas.add(data);

            youtubeIndex++;
        }
    }

    return datas;
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but it displayed all the articles first, then the youtube items, i'll really love to have them shuffled

Comment: It depend on logic in merge(Articel[] articles, List<YouTubeItem> items) method. Tell me which kind of shuffled do you want ? Even position -> article, odd position -> youtubeitem ? or you want random item for random position ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll love random item for random position

Comment: Check my edited answer, I've add mergeRandom() method

Comment: Thanks a lot,but I get out of memory exception, I think using odd and even position will be more realistic, I'll be glad if you can help with that

Comment: Oh, I have tested this method in my computer and it work normally. About odd and even position, I can not help you right now because I'm in working time. I'll back for you later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169158/discussion-between-truong-giang-dam-and-tolulope).

Comment: your answer is okey for if i load the data at a time but if i need to implement lazyloading feature like call the api after user scroll 10 item from recycle view . so anyone can explan that situation "? can you check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730109/how-to-show-multiple-data-soruce-data-in-single-recycle-view-or-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Make one `interface` to implement your data pojo class like below..

```
public interface Parent{
}
```

Then pojo class like

```
public class User implements Parent{
    private String name,addres;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddres() {
        return addres;
    }

    public void setAddres(String addres) {
        this.addres = addres;
    }
}
```

Then add all the data into parent list and bind into adapter ..
Adapter bind data according to pojo class like below..

```
public class SearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Parent> {
    Context context;
    Parent parent[] = null;
        public SearchListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Parent[] parent) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, parent);
        this.context = context;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        final View outerContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_list_item, parent, false);
        if (this.parent != null) {
            Parent temp = this.parent[position];
            if (temp instanceof FoodItem) {
                final FoodItem item = (FoodItem) temp;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is okey for if i load the data at a time but if i need to implement lazyloading feature like call the api after user scroll 10 item from recycle view . so anyone can explan that situation "? can you check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730109/how-to-show-multiple-data-soruce-data-in-single-recycle-view-or-adapter

Answer (score 0):

use this function to merge the data and use this in your adapter :

```
public List<Data> merge(Articel[] articles, List<YouTubeItem> items) {


        int counter = 0,counter1=0,size=0;


        size = articles.length + items.size();

        List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size;i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {

                if(counter1<articles.length){

                Article article = articles[counter1];
                Data data = new Data();
                data.article = article;
                data.youTubeItem = null;
                data.type = 1;
                datas.add(data);
                counter1++;

                }else if(counter<items.size()){

                 YouTubeItem item = items.get(counter);
                Data data = new Data();
                data.article = null;
                data.youTubeItem = item;
                data.type = 2;
                datas.add(data);
                counter++;
                }

            } else {

                if(counter<items.size()){

                   YouTubeItem item = items.get(counter);
                Data data = new Data();
                data.article = null;
                data.youTubeItem = item;
                data.type = 2;
                datas.add(data);
                counter++;
                }else if(counter1<articles.length){

                Article article = articles[counter1];
                Data data = new Data();
                data.article = article;
                data.youTubeItem = null;
                data.type = 1;
                datas.add(data);
                counter1++;
                }

            }

        }


        return datas;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i get ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: No, I get it in the merge function

Comment: Thanks but subtracting the lists in my own case returns only five items since articles.length = 20 and items.size() = 15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169150/discussion-between-hitesh-sarsava-and-tolulope).

Comment: your answer is okey for if i load the data at a time but if i need to implement lazyloading feature like call the api after user scroll 10 item from recycle view . so anyone can explan that situation "? can you check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730109/how-to-show-multiple-data-soruce-data-in-single-recycle-view-or-adapter